# Under what jurisdiction is the ISS?

Tags: international-law, international, space

Under what jurisdiction is the ISS? If a crime is to be committed inside the International Space Station, under whose jurisdiction would the criminals be prosecuted? Is there a mechanism or international treaty that determines how the criminals and victims would be handled in the event of a crime? And does each section have a different jurisdiction, if there is any jurisdiction?

Comment: have you looked at maritime/aircraft laws as well as those applying to multinational contexts like perhaps Antarctic *expeditions* (planes/ships/bases would be under "home country" law, at a guess)?  it's not a bad question, but where's the research?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is something called the [Intergovernmental Agreement](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/International_Space_Station/International_Space_Station_legal_framework). It says that each country has jurisdiction over its own nationals aboard the ISS. So for example, if a Japanese astronaut sexually assaults a Russian astronaut, then the Japanese government would be in charge of prosecution. This agreement applies only to the ISS. It isn't a more general law about all human space travel.

A US astronaut named Anne McClain was accused of committing a white-collar crime remotely from the ISS in 2019, and the jurisdiction for this fell to the US under the agreement. The accusation seems to have been a false one made by her estranged wife.

The rule is different from the standard rule under maritime law, which is that the country that has jurisdiction is the one under whose flag the ship is registered (assuming the crime doesn't occur in territorial waters).

Comment: Not so different: *so the elements they provide (e.g. laboratories) are assimilated to the territories of the Partners States.* but still a very good response to the question.

Comment: This does get slightly more complicated in regard to British astronauts and contributions, because there is no such thing as UK national law, because the UK consists of three separate and equal legal jurisdictions. But it doesn't look like anyone has tried to test that yet.

Comment: It's interesting that the *accused* person's government run the prosecution instead of the alleged victim's country.  I think I understand why, though.

Comment: @user1937198: *'Scotland forever!'* banner in space...? I like it